# How to solve Twitter API Error 403 after function search_tweets in R?

Tags: r, api, error-handling, twitter, tweets

I have created a developer account on Twitter, set it to the “read and write” settings, and now try to search for tweets with the keyword “vinted”. However, it gives me the 403 Twitter API Failed error.

Until the get_token() command I did not receive any errors.

```
# I have specified my keys before this

token <- create_token(app = appname, consumer_key = consumer_key, consumer_secret = consumer_secret, access_token = access_token, access_secret = access_secret)

get_token()

tweets.vinted <- search_tweets("vinted")
```

Error: Twitter API failed [403]
Check error message at https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not pass the token to the `search_tweets` function.

```
search_tweets("vinted", token=token)
```